# intellij idea module default "user.dir"

Tags: eclipse, module, path, intellij-idea, projects

I am fresh about intellij idea. I just import several projects from `eclipse`, and it's modules in intellij idea.
I run one main in one module and get `file can not found` exception. I check the `user.dir` parameter and find it direct to another module(that module is the first module when I import eclipse projects).

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

I just want set the user.dir to that module directory when I run the main in one module. How to set it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Create a `Run/Debug configuration` for your Main class (the easiest way is to right-click on it and choose *Save 'MyClass.main()'*).
2. Now, find your configuration (named after your class) on the main toolbar dropdown and choose *Edit Configurations*
3. For `VM options`, put `-Duser.dir=whatever`

Alternatively, setting `Working directory` might be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, I set the  Working directory  to  $MODULE_DIR$  ,it can give me what I want. I also find set default to this:  Run->Edit configurations->Defaults.  All the application EXCEPT Run/Debug configuration you create manually will use the default setting.